# How to find and evaluate a freelance commission-based sales person for digital agency work?

Tags: sales

We are a growing digital agency, with over 8 years of good work, well known clients and great success stories. Our clients are mostly in the US and we are located in Colombia.

In the past we have won clients through client references but we want to be more selective now, particularly in terms of project budget.

We offer design, programming, online marketing (SEO/SEM) and some social media services.

How can I find and evaluate a freelance commission-based sales person for digital agency work?

Comment: Hey John, welcome to Freelancing SE, a Q&A site. I replaced the last part of the question body "Does anyone have experience with this" with the more concrete question in the title. On our site, the best questions are asked in Q&A format. With that said, I'm not 100% sure this is on-topic, but we'll see how it goes. Good luck!

Comment: No probs @jmort253 - thought it would also interest a lot of the others here from the point of view of business development.

Comment: I'm really not sure this fits in the "freelancing" realm. Advice on hiring a sales agent for your company is pretty far from freelancing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treat this just as would if you where hiring a paid employee, except that as freelancer, they can work remotely and the hours that they choose.

Develop your job description, including an overview of your company (what you do, benefits of working with you), the roles and responsibilities, the 'skill-sets' (hard skills and soft skills) you are looking for.

Specify that this is a commission based role and whether or not training is provided.

Ask for references and check those.

You will find that most people are looking for at least some sort of base pay - but you never know - I have seen digital marketing agencies that have done quite well with commission only staff.

Post on the job boards (Google "Job Boards for Freelancers" and don't forget about job boards like Craigslist, Monster, Workopolis).

You can have a 'Careers' section on your web site too, and post the job description there.

Also get the word out on social networks (business and professional) and let people know  a) to tell their friends; and b) who to get in-touch with if interested.

To attract good talent on a commission structure, you will need to make the potential pay very rewarding.  To keep that talent, you will need to work with your commissioned sales staff to make sure that excellent remuneration is achievable.

In particular, for commissioned sales jobs, you will be looking for professionalism, very outgoing personality - someone with a lot of energy, initiative and especially confidence.

If your commission structure is good and your services are 'sell-able,' then both you and the commissioned sales person should have an idea, after about 1 week, whether or not you have good job fit for the salesperson and a good salesperson for the job.

If they show promise, reward them and continue to help them get better at sales.

However, if after a week, it becomes obvious that they aren't showing promise, get them to move on.

Expect to have a high turnover rate for commission only sales positions - the most talented commissioned based sales people are like mercenaries - they'll go where they make they believe they can make most the most money, and why not?

So think about the payment structure and if that is what you want for your company.

Comment: +1 excellent answer